# Разместить текст как в макете

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если не готовое решение, то хотя бы идею

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.container-row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-row">
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете? Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-row">
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете? Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-row">
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете? Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете? Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете? Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, который раз Вы мне помогаете)

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись и без `flex` (доработал код из [ответа @soledar10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677789/208074)):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.container-row {
  display: table-row;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-row">
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете? Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-row">
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете? Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-row">
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете? Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете? Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
    <div class="item">Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете? Здравствуйте! Как расположить текст как в макете?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```